# Matlab: How to conditionally select a subset of a matrix based on a row function?

Tags: matlab, matrix, subset

I have a vector like this, which represents horizontal/vertical dimensions on a board

```
Hor   Verti
 1    2
 2    3 
 4    1 
 2    3      
 2    2 
 1    4 
 ..... and many more
```

I also have an starting vector of (1, 1) . I want to sub-select all rows of this matrix where either horizontal == 1 and vertical is +-2 units away, or vertical == 1 and horizontal = +-2.

Think of like a rook on a mini-4x4 chess board, that is constrained to moving 2 spaces at a time. I want to find all the valid spaces that it can move to out of a series of proposed spaces, it is ok that some of the proposals exists more than once, because they are proposed by different people.

I want subset of proposals where

> ```
> [ (Hori== sInitial(1) && (Vert - sInitial(2) <=2) )
>  ||           (Vert == sInitial(2) && (Hori - sInitial(1) <=2) ) 
>    ]
> ```

Is it possible to do this without a for-loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a 4x4 grid of possible positions:

```
>> [x,y] = ndgrid(1:4,1:4)
x =
     1     1     1     1
     2     2     2     2
     3     3     3     3
     4     4     4     4
y =
     1     2     3     4
     1     2     3     4
     1     2     3     4
     1     2     3     4

>> xy = [x(:) y(:)];
```

If the player is in position `pos = [2 3]` and allowed to move up to 2 spaces (either horizontal or vertical), the possible moves would be:

```
>> idx = (pdist2(xy, pos, 'cityblock') <= 2) & any(bsxfun(@eq, xy, pos), 2);
>> M = reshape(double(idx), [4 4]); M(pos(1),pos(2)) = nan;
M =
     0     0     1     0
     1     1   NaN     1
     0     0     1     0
     0     0     1     0
```

(I've marked the initial position with `NaN`, possible moves with `1`, rest of grid with `0`).

or in terms of coordinates:

```
>> coords = xy(idx,:)
coords =
     2     1
     2     2
     1     3
     2     3
     3     3
     4     3
     2     4
```

The above [`pdist2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html) function computes the [Manhattan distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry).

Comment: the player is allowed to move two spaces but only in one direction at at a time :p   do you play chess ;)

Comment: oops, sorry. I fixed it by adding the additional constraint! Maybe that's not the fastest way to compute it for a small 2d grid, but the above code can be generalized to work on N-D grids. Then again, I've never seen chess played in 3D grids :)

Answer (score 1):

That's easy. Given some data

```
data = [1    2
        2    3 
        4    1 
        2    3      
        2    2 
        1    4
        3    1];
```

simply do:

```
row_indices = find( (data(:,1)==1 | data(:,2)==1) & abs(data(:,1)-data(:,2))<=2 )
data(row_indices,:)
```

Comment: thanks! but this code tends to miscount :(  underestimates the number of valid proposals